# helm error on a vlaue in the values.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to replace a value in my configMap yaml with a value from the value.yaml file.

My values.yaml files includes fields that are referenced from my deployment.yaml file, and they all work well wit no problem.

I was trying to replace now a hard coded value in my configMap.yaml with a value taken from the values.yaml file.

When I run the "helm template"command, everything is OK and no error is displayed.
However, when I run the "upgrade command"it fails with this error:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: cannot patch "oct-2-files" with kind ConfigMap:    
"" is invalid: patch: Invalid value: "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"data\":{\"keys\":\"\\n\\n##server.http.port=4442\\n\\n\\nbase.request.host=https://localhost\\n\\nbase.request.port=8060\\n\\nlte.device.provisioning.simulate.mode=false\\n\\n\\npostgres.cluster=${POSTGRES_CLUSTER}\\n\\npostgres.host=${POSTGRES_HOST}\\n\\npostgres.port=${POSTGRES_PORT}\\n\\npostgres.dbname=${POSTGRES_DB}\\n\\n\\n\\njdbc.user=${POSTGRES_USER}\\n\\njdbc.pass=${POSTGRES_PASS}\\n\\n\\n\\n#spring.data.mongodb.host=${MONGO_HOST}\\n\\nspring.data.mongodb.uri=${MONGO_URI}\\n\\n\\nspring.redis.password=${REDIS_PASS}\\n\\n\\nspring.redis.host=${REDIS_HOST}\\n\\nspring.redis.port=${REDIS_PORT}\\n\\n\\n\\n\\nactivemq.cluster=${AMQ_CLUSTER}\\n\\nactivemq.server.address=${AMQ_HOST}\\n\\nactivemq.server.port=${AMQ_PORT}\\n\\n\\n\\nlocation.mapitem.image_path=/usr/src/octopus/storage/\\n\\n\\n\\n## OCR\\n\\n\\nocr.tesseract.data.path=/usr/src/octopus/backend/tesseract\\n\\n\\n\\n# define if image saving is enabled\\n\\nocr.image.saving.enabled=true\\n\\n\\n# the path for the image storing folder\\n\\nocr.image.path=/usr/src/octopus/storage/\\n\\n\\n# cron pattern for image clean process\\n\\nocr.image.clean.cron.expression=0 0/10 * * * *\\n\\n\\nocr.image.engine=fe\\n\\n\\n\\n## Debugging\\n\\n# To enable debugging activate the desired properties below and restart the\\nbackend container, e.g.:\\n\\n# docker restart octopus-be-dev-1\\n\\n\\n# logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG\\n\\nlogging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO\\n\\n\\n# logging.level.com.mot.nsa=DEBUG\\n\\nlogging.level.com.mot.nsa=INFO\\n\\n\\n# logging.level.root=DEBUG\\n\\nlogging.level.root=INFO\\n\\n\\n# logging.level.org.apache.camel=on\\n\\nlogging.level.org.apache.camel=off\\n\\n\\n# log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG\\n\\nlog4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO\\n\\n\\n# logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG\\n\\nlogging.level.org.hibernate=INFO\\n\\n\\n# hibernate.show_sql=true\\n\\nhibernate.show_sql=false\\n\",\"server.http.port\":4442},\"kind\":\"ConfigMap\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"meta.helm.sh/release-name\":\"helmoct\",\"meta.helm.sh/release-namespace\":\"default\"},\"creationTimestamp\":\"2022-06-23T07:05:20Z\",\"labels\":{\"app.kubernetes.io/managed-by\":\"Helm\"},\"managedFields\":[{\"manager\":\"kubectl-create\",\"operation\":\"Update\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"time\":\"2022-03-14T15:50:44Z\",\"fieldsType\":\"FieldsV1\",\"fieldsV1\":{\"f:data\":{}}},{\"manager\":\"helm\",\"operation\":\"Update\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"time\":\"2022-06-27T04:35:27Z\",\"fieldsType\":\"FieldsV1\",\"fieldsV1\":{\"f:data\":{\"f:keys\":{}}}}],\"name\":\"octopus-2-files\",\"namespace\":\"default\",\"resourceVersion\":\"738993\",\"uid\":\"e43715b4-cdb9-4c13-94a4-2877ec975597\"}}":    
**json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field ConfigMap.data of type string**
```

This is my values.yaml file:

```
version: 164   
dummyhostval: 1.13.19.196   
mainfeport: 9090   
proxyhost: 1.13.19.73   
httpport: 4442    #this is the only value from the configMap yaml
```

An this is my configMap yaml:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: octopus-2-files
data:
  server.http.port: {{ .Values."httpport" }}
  keys: |


    ##server.http.port=4442


    base.request.host=https://localhost

    base.request.port=8060

    lte.device.provisioning.simulate.mode=false


    postgres.cluster=${POSTGRES_CLUSTER}

    postgres.host=${POSTGRES_HOST}

    postgres.port=${POSTGRES_PORT}

    postgres.dbname=${POSTGRES_DB}
```

Why does helm thinks it is a number, and how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 11):

The error is telling you that you can't use a number in a configmap. You need to make it all strings.

> cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field ConfigMap.data of type string

So quote the server port:

```yaml
server.http.port: {{ .Values.httpport | quote }}
```

Comment: (The original output value contains only digits and no quotation marks, so by YAML's standard rules it's a number and not a string; using `quote` surrounds it in double quotes which forces it to be a string.)